# How to find the common elements of 2 cell arrays that contain randperm elements?

Tags: matlab, cell, cell-array

I have two cell arrays which may not be of the same size. Elements of cell arrays is `randperm` of an integer number. `randperm` data Type is double array. How can I find common elements of two cell arrays?

For example:

```
Q1 = {[1 2 3 4], [3 2 4 1], [4 2 1 3]}
Q2 = {[2 4 3 1], [1 2 3 4], [1 2 4 3]}
```

As I said elements of cell arrays are `randperm`. I want the output of above example be "Element-1 of `Q1` i.e. `[1 2 3 4]` since it is also present in `Q2`.
Note: Cell Arrays may have different number of columns...

Comment: I want index of elements which have same value.for example:                       Q1=([1 2 3 4],[3 2 4 1],[4 2 1 3]) & Q2=([2 4 3 1],[1 2 3 4],[1 2 4 3])           as I said element of array cell is randperm. I want the output of above example be "element 1 of Q1 is same as element 2 of Q2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vertically concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) the matrices inside the cell arrays and use `intersect` with the [`'rows'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btcnv0p-12) flag. i.e.

```
Q1={[1 2 3 4], [3 2 4 1], [4 2 1 3]}; 
Q2={[2 4 3 1], [1 2 3 4], [1 2 4 3]};
Qout = intersect(vertcat(Q1{:}), vertcat(Q2{:}), 'rows');

%>> Qout
%Qout =
%     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: Thanks so mush. that was useful.

Comment: Sorry. I have a problem for using above solution. My cell arrays don't have same number of columns. and I get the error:                                                               Inputs A and B must be matrices with the same number of columns in the 'rows' case.

Comment: @Bahar If they are really, as you said, *randperm* of an integer no. then  each matrix inside the cell array will always have the same number of columns. Provide a sample of `Q1` and `Q2` that satisfy the stated condition and give the error that you mentioned

Comment: for example I have A_C2 that is a 1*1 cell and its element is {[]} & the second cell array is a 1*2 cell and its elements are {[],[5 2 3 4 1]}. in first steps of my algorithm cell arrays may have empty arrays..                                             the error is :Inputs A and B must be matrices with the same number of columns in the 'rows' case.                                                                                                        when I enter: Qout = intersect(vertcat(A_C2{1}), vertcat(k_C2{2}), 'rows')

Comment: @Bahar empty arrays do not qualify as *randperm* of an integer number

Comment: and when I enter Qout = intersect(vertcat(A_C2{:}), vertcat(k_C2{:}), 'rows') . The Error is: Inputs A and B must be matrices with the same number of columns in the 'rows' case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Now is there any Solution for my Problem?

Comment: For example is there a way to remove empty arrays of my cells?

Comment: @Bahar Use `Q2(~cellfun(@isempty,Q2))` for removing them from `Q2`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11505101/).

Comment: in the solution Qout = intersect(vertcat(Q1{:}), vertcat(Q2{:}), 'rows'); for above question, Is there any way to get index of common elements?

Comment: @Bahar yes!  Read the documentation links, I linked in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using two loops and check all off them.

```
q1=[1 2 3 4; 3 2 4 1; 4 2 1 3];
q2=[2 4 3 1; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 4 3];

%find the size of matrix
[m1,n1] = size(q1);
[m2] = size(q2,1);

for (ii=1:m1)
    for (jj=1:m2)
        %if segments are equal, it will return 1
        %if sum of same segment = 4 it means they are same
        if ( sum( q1(ii,:) == q2(jj,:) ) == n1)
            ii %result of q1
            jj %result of q2
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The OP has two cell arrays, not simple matrices